# installing flutter on linux lite 5

Tags: linux, flutter, android-studio

-i'm using linux lite 5
and android studio (arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 2).
-i've downloaded flutter sdk but i can't install it.
-i searched the internet but i couldn't find a solution.
-so maybe help ??

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does it show any kind of error message?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this
https://gist.github.com/CloudLinuxDeveloper/e7f84a745ce71fedba669a5d683edbf8

or also u can try to install in from git
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git